# Can I force the user profile to render in a language other than the current user's language?

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

I am trying to render user profiles in both English and Japanese in `user-profile.tpl.php`:

```
$render = user_view($user, 'nopic', 'en');
print render($render);
$render = user_view($user, 'nopic', 'ja');
print render($render);
```

However, this always returns the translated version of the user's profile twice for the logged-in user's language (both Japanese if viewed from a Japanese language account, and both English if viewed from an English language account).

Is it possible to force the output to render the profile as if viewed from a user with a language other than the account language?

Comment: That feeling you get when you continue to research your question, and a Google search shows the question you asked five minutes ago as the first result...

Comment: Have you tried to use the third param "$langcode" ?
function user_view($account, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL)

Comment: @ZakariaElhariri Yes, as shown in the code example in the question, I am using the `$langcode` parameter.  But that appears to be getting overidden somehow.